# Are there any connections between metric space and inner product space

Tags: metric-spaces, inner-products

As mentioned in title, are the any connections between inner product space(well, here we talk about only real space) and metric space? I kind of notice that the axioms satisfied by both inner product and metric are almost the same.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, every inner product space is a metric space, with the "Euclidean metric" defined by
$$
d(x,y) = \sqrt{\langle x-y, x-y \rangle}
$$

Not every metric on a vector space comes from an inner product though (For instance, $l^1$, the space of summable sequences, is one such example)

Comment: So what you mean is inner product space is metric space but not the vice versa?

Comment: Please read my answer below: a metric space can just be a finite set

Answer (score 8):

There is even an intermediate step: in your setting one can prove that

$$\text{inner product}\Rightarrow \text{norm}\Rightarrow \text{metric/distance},$$

where $\Rightarrow$ means "induces". A first, major difference between the above structures is that  inner products and norms require a vector space structure, while metrics are defined on sets.